# Using uninstallstring through PowerShell to uninstall program

Tags: powershell

The issue I'm having right now is that when I go to run the code through PowerShell, it is changing the value of the uninstall string and adding the variable name before it. The result i'm hoping for is this.

```
MsiExec.exe /X{2C5B24AD-9F13-52A1-KA2N-8K4A41DC9L4G}
```

But the result I'm getting from the variable after replacing the `/I` with an `/X` and doing `.Trim()` is the following:

```
@{UninstallString=/X{2C5B24AD-9F13-52A1-KA2N-8K4A41DC9L4G}}
```

So I was wondering if you guys would be able to tell me from my code below where I'm going wrong.

I have to replace the `/I` with `/X`, because the uninstall string first comes back like this `MsiExec.exe /I{2C5B24AD-9F13-52A1-KA2N-8K4A41DC9L4G}`, and I'm trying to uninstall, not install.

```
if ($Uninstall_str) {
    #run uninstall here
    try {
        $Uninstall_str = $Uninstall_str -replace 'MsiExec.exe /I', '/X'
        $Uninstall_str = $Uninstall_str.Trim()
        Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -Arg "$Uninstall_str /qb" -Wait
    } catch {
        Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Output $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-Warning "Error unintalling."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't expand the `UninstallString` value when reading it from the registry. Your code for doing that probably looks somewhat like this:

```
$Uninstall_str = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\...\Uninstall\Something' |
                 Select-Object UninstallString
```

Replace that with

```
$Uninstall_str = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\...\Uninstall\Something' |
                 Select-Object -Expand UninstallString
```

and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the @{uninstallstring all I needed to do was specify what I was trimming on this line

```
$Uninstall_str = $Uninstall_str.Trim()
```

So that line changed to the following to receive the results I was looking for.

```
$Uninstall_str = $Uninstall_str.Trim("@{UninstallString=")
```

Comment: That would only remove `@{UninstallString=` from the beginning of the string, but leave a spurious trailing `}` at the end. Don't do that. Fix the root cause of the issue instead, as outlined in my answer.